# AJAX issue piling up activity indicators on each click of a deleted question review

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, ajax

Edge case and minor technical issue.

- use an account with less than 10k reputation
- visit a review of a deleted question, like https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/16294284
- click on `inline` and `side-by-side` buttons alternatively, many times

The AJAX activity indicator is piling up on each click:

[image]

Chrome 60 on macOS Sierra; I'm in China.